# Sonar api : what is the purpose of analysisid?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm following the guide to be able to control job status based on sonar report : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Breaking+the+CI+Build

Here, it is explained you get a taskid ,and when task is completed you retrieve a analysisId that can be used to get the qualitygate info using /api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=

I would have expected that this analysisId keeps persist and provides the same report over the time.
It does not sound to be the case. From my experience, the api project_status is always returning the last valid report, and past analysis are no more kept.

Here is the protocol I used to demonstrate

trigger first analysis , providing me a first report :

`api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=AWEnFPG63R-cEOOz4bmK`
with a status `ERROR` and `coverage = 80%`

then i trigger the second analysis that give me another id:

`api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=AWEnHBj53R-cEOOz4bny`
with a status `OK` and `coverage=90%`

so now , if i call back the first analysisId `api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=AWEnFPG63R-cEOOz4bmK` -> the report has been changed and is similar as the last one

Can someone explain me the concept of analysisId? cause this is not really an identifier of analysis here.

Comment: What is your version of SonarQube? 5.3 is quite old and newer versions offer a better way to do this.

Comment: my version is 6.7.1

Answer (score 0):

The link you provide in your question is to an archived, rather old version of the documentation. Since your comment reveals that you are on a current (6.7.1) version of SonarQube, then you'll benefit from using the current documentation.

In current versions, [Webhooks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Webhooks) allow you to notify external systems once analysis report processing is complete. The SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins makes it [very easy to use webhooks in a pipeline](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline), but even if you're not using Jenkins pipelines, you should still use webhooks instead of trying to retrieve this all manually. As shown in the docs (linked earlier) the webhook payload includes analysis timestamp, project name and key, and quality gate status.

Comment: thanks for your answer @g-ann-sonarsource-team. I understand webhook is a new way, but has some limitations. 
Nonetheless, the api I use is still described in the 6.7.1 documentation, presenting the parameter 'analysisId'.... so my question
My context is jenkins 1.x with automatic generation of commit jobs (numerous). They all post sonar:result for projects and i just want to wait and get the correct triggered analysis. If `analysisId` would have stayed consistent over the time - which sounds implicit by its name... that would have been easy.

Comment: We have same issue and webhooks are impossible to implement for our complex environment in cause of necessarity to control quality gates independently. Is there is a bug in the SonarQube api or quality gates historical storage?